# Why doesn't Windows Live Messenger work on Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, web, instant-messaging, http, windows-live-messenger

If Google chat can be integrated over http:80 seamlessly in the gmail interface in Chrome, why can't Messenger? Is it a play on Microsoft's part to prevent novice users from moving away from IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web Service [Meebo](http://www.meebo.com/) does exactly that. Microsoft simply doesn't see it as something that's worthwhile.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try http://demo.java2script.org/gtalk/ (it has GTalk, MSN, Y!, AIM and ICQ).

Answer (score 0):

It can be, see [MSN Web Messenger](http://webmessenger.msn.com).

Once you sign in, you see a list of contacts.

To actually use it as MSN Messenger, click on sign in on the drop down menu in the top right:

[image]

You can then use it to chat to people on a standard web page (Port 80 (or 443))

[image]

Comment: Did you take these screenshots from Chrome? That doesn't work at all for me for some reason.